# Trying to use 2 isset for 1 button

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a duplicate -

I'm willing to know how can I do this, because as it is my code is not working.

```
 echo'<form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Test" name="Test"></form> ';

if (isset($_POST['Test'])) { 
 $item_name="Plume";
 $id_vente=2;
 }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
// Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no `vendre1plume` or `submit` elements in your form. Just for being of *type* `submit` it doesn't sets `$_POST['submit']`, it must the the name of the input instead.

Comment: you have only $_POST['Test']

Comment: if(isset($_POST['Test'])) { 
// Do some stuff
}

only this will work

Comment: Yes, vendre1plume = test, forgot about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, you need to make sure you are fetching and checking the correct key values. `name="Test"` is the key value, so you need to look for that. To change the form to be able to match your two `if` conditions:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Test" value="bugs" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="TEST" />
</form>
```

Submitting this form will output:

```
Array
(
    [Test] => bugs
    [submit] => TEST
)
```

This will satisfy the `isset($_POST['Test'])` and the `isset($_POST['submit'])` condition.

I find it's easier to do an action name:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- Hiding an action word will tell which script to run -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_some_action" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="TEST" />
</form>
```

This would submit:

```
Array
(
    [action] => do_some_action
    [submit] => TEST
)
```

Then I would have some observer that would listen for actions:

```
<?php
# Check that an action has been sent
if(!empty($_POST['action'])) {
    # Create a switch to do the action
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case('do_some_other_action'):
            // Do some other script
            break;
        case('do_some_action'):
            // Do some script
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The hidden input was exactly what i was looking for, thanks you !

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_key_exists('vendre1plume', $_POST)` instead of `isset()`.

Comment: Checking using your method will not make their script work. It will produce the same results because there is no `vendre1plume` or `submit` key in their form. You are just suggesting an alternate way to to check if the key is set...which it won't be.